# C DLL and Python CTypes - Different Return in Release / Debug

Tags: c++, python, debugging, dll, printing

I have a DLL that exists solely for the purpose of exposing a handful of Printer API Functions to Python.  One of the methods looks like this:

```
extern "C" DOEXPORT const wchar_t* P_EnumPrintersW() {
    DWORD dwneeded(0), dwreturned(0);
    BOOL test = ::EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS,
        NULL,
        4,
        NULL,
        0,
        &dwneeded,
        &dwreturned);
    std::vector<byte> printbuf;
    printbuf.resize(dwneeded);
    test = ::EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS,
        NULL,
        4,
        &printbuf[0],
        printbuf.size(),
        &dwneeded,
        &dwreturned);
    PRINTER_INFO_4* print4 = static_cast<PRINTER_INFO_4*>((LPVOID) &printbuf[0]);
    wstring result;
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwreturned; ++i) {
        result += L",";
        result += print4[i].pPrinterName;
    }
    return result.c_str();
}
```

This works generally as expected and I'm able to call into it with this code over in the python world:

```
dll = ctypes.CDLL('<path to dll>')
dll.P_EnumPrintersW.restype = ctypes.c_wchar_p
dllopts = dll.P_EnumPrintersW().split(',')
```

And I normally expect dllopts to look like this:

```
[u'', u'\u8fd9\u662f\u4e00\u4e2a\u8003\u9a8c', ... ]
```

Yes, I expect the blank string as the first entry, and the whole reason for this dll is to handle Printer Names that have Wide Character Names for language support.  That's all fine and well until I build my DLL in debug mode. Then, instead of the result I expect, I get this:

```
[u'\udddd\udddd\udddd...']
```

Only one value, and every character is `\udddd`.  Wat?  Is that some side effect of ctypes not knowing how to deal with the dll when it's built in debug mode?  Is that some effect of the memory mapping of the dll being in debug mode?  I can attach to my python process (and through it, the dll as it is called into) and verify the value of `result` before it's returned and it looks correct, but it does not make it to my python program.  I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: Did my answer was useful?

Comment: Why don't you say why my answser did not helped you. Pretty sure that returning local result.c_str() as wchar_t* is undefined behavior.

Comment: @manuell - Sorry, it's taken me time to get back to this and do more testing - I have had other projects take the forefront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a pointer managed by a local variable. When `wstring result` goes out of scope, using the pointer returned by `result.c_str()` is undefined behavior.

Examples of solutions:

1. You could make the P_EnumPrintersW function **receive** a pointer,
   with a corresponding size information, update the memory pointed to
   with your final string content, and then return the pointer. The
   memory must be allocated in Python prior to calling the function.
2. Another solution would be for your function to return a pointer to
   malloced memory. Youd would have to add another API, doing the
   corresponding `free`.

Comment: When I finally made it back to this your first option addressed the difference.  Thanks much friend.